# Emacs - copy/paste error on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-yosemite

Today when trying copy/pasting to/from emacs I had the following behaviour :

- copy from osx to emacs : error message "kill ring is empty"
- copy from emacs to emacs : no matter what I copy, the text pasted would be something like : `2016-05-03 15:14:32.237 pbpaste[24394:8180457] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : Lock timeout`

What could be the cause of this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted and it is working fine now, so I suspect this is a bug in OSX (also see [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7493153?start=0&tstart=0)).